# Integral inequality: Prove $\int_0^y g_x(x,z) \, dz \le 0$ or $\ge 0$ where $d(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) \, dy$ and $g(x,y) = \frac{f(x,y)}{d(x)}.$

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Suppose $f : [0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ is smooth, $d(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y) dy,$ and $g(x) = \frac{f(x,y)}{d(x)}$ is the normalized version of $f.$ How can I prove that $h(x,y) := \int_0^y \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x,z) dz \ge 0$ or $\le 0$ for all $0 \le x, y \le 1$?

You may assume $d > 0$ everywhere. I have the additional condition (#) that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \le 0$ when $x \le y$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) \ge 0$ when $x \ge y,$ but if you can prove it without (#), that would be nice. You can also assume $f$ is symmetric, but it doesn't help.

With (#), I did the case that $d$ is constant. Without (#) but with the assumption that the curve $g_x = 0$ is a function when restricted to $0 \le x \le 1,$ you can also prove the inequality. Let $C$ be the curve and check the cases $(x,y)$ below/above $C$ separately, using the fact that $h(x,1) = 0$ for the case corresponding to $g_x \ge 0.$

Motivation: In the process of proving something else, I've defined an integral operator, found it to be precisely $T_{-h},$ and expect either it or $T_h$ to be positive, which means the inequality mentioned earlier. Proving positivity is the last missing step. There is no freedom to choose the operator and I need it to be positive or my proof fails and the result I'm trying to prove is just false.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it was hard to me to understand what is going on in your question, so I provide a partial answer.

I think an interesting special case of the question is when the function $f$ is polynomial. Its investigation can lead either to a counterexample or to a positive answer for all $f$, which can be sufficiently smoothly approximated by polynomials.

Note first that
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,z)=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{f(x,y)}{d(x)}\right)=
\frac{f_x(x,y)d(x)-d'(x)f(x,y)}{d(x)^2}.$$

Thus

$$h(x,y)=\int_{0}^{y} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,z)dz=\int_{0}^{y} \frac{f_x(x,z)d(x)-d'(x)f(x,z)}{d(x)^2}dz=$$
$$\frac 1{d(x)^2}\left(d(x)\int_{0}^{y} f_x(x,z)dz - d'(x)\int_{0}^{y} f(x,z)dz\right).$$

Thus $h(x,y)$ is nonnegative (resp. nonpositive) for each $0\le x,y\le 1$ iff
$$k(x,y)=d(x)\int_{0}^{y} f_x(x,z)dz - d'(x)\int_{0}^{y} f(x,z)dz$$ is nonnegative (resp. nonpositive) for each $0\le x,y\le 1$.

Now assume that $f(x,y)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^iy^j$. Then
$f_x(x,y)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}ix^{i-1}y^j$.
So
$$\int_{0}^{y} f(x,z)dz=
\int_{0}^{y}\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^iz^j\right)dz=
\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^i \int_{0}^{y}z^j dz=
\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}}{j+1}x^iy^{j+1}.$$

Similarly,
$$\int_{0}^{y} f_x(x,z)dz=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}i}{j+1}x^{i-1}y^{j+1}.$$

Also we have
$$d(x)=\int_{0}^{1} \sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^iy^j dy=
\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} a_{ij}x^i\int_{0}^{1} y^j dy=
\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}}{j+1}x^i.$$
So
$$d'(x)=\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}i}{j+1}x^{i-1}.$$

Thus

$$k(x,y)=\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}}{j+1}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}i}{j+1}x^{i-1}y^{j+1}\right)-\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}i}{j+1}x^{i-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} \frac{a_{ij}}{j+1}x^iy^{j+1}\right).$$

Putting $b_{ij}=\frac{a_{i,j}}{j+1}$ for each $i,j\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$, we obtain
$$k(x,y)=\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}ix^{i-1}y^{j+1}\right)-\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}ix^{i-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}x^iy^{j+1}\right)=$$
$$\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i,k=0}^{n} b_{ik}ix^{i-1}y^{k+1}\right)-\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}ix^{i-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i,k=0}^{n} b_{ik}x^iy^{k+1}\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}y^k\left(
\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} b_{ik}ix^{i-1}\right)-\left(\sum_{i,j=0}^{n} b_{ij}ix^{i-1}\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n} b_{ik}x^i\right)\right)=$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}y^k\sum_{\ell=0}^{2n-1} x^\ell\sum_{p+q=\ell+1}(q-p)b_{qk}\sum_{j=0}^{n} b_{pj}.$$

Moreover, for small $n$ we can look for a counterexample by trying the coefficients $a_{ij}$ for $i,j\in \{0,1,\dots,n\}$.
For instance, we can put $n=2$, all $a_{ij}=1/9$, but $a_{11}=a_{20}=0$. Then $k$ attains on $[0,1]^2$ both positive and negative values, see the fragment of Mathcad's screenshot below:

[image: the fragment of Mathcad's screenshot]

Comment: This is a counterexample with symmetric $f$ and $(#)$ violated. So now I know the condition is necessary. Unfortunate that there's no simpler polynomial counterexample, this leaves open the possibility that even when $(#)$ is true there's a counterexample but far more complicated.

Comment: @Displayname I did not think about this much, but maybe there exists a not very complicated counterexample with (#), where the latter is provided by the condition $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y)=(x-y)p(x,y)$, where the polynomial $p(x,y)$ is nonnegative on $[0,1]^2$.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This a valid answer for the original question. It has now been modified.

Let $f(x,y)=\frac {x+y} 2$. Then, $d(x)=\frac   12 (x+\frac  1 2)$ and  $g(x,y)=\frac {x+y}{x+\frac 1 2 }$. We have, $g_x(x,y)=\frac {(x+\frac 1  2)-(x+y)} {(x+\frac 1  2)^{2}}$.  Note that $g_x(x,y) > 0$ if $y< \frac 1  2$. Hence, your claim is false.

Comment: Question updated. If $h \ge 0$ always, it's not a problem since I can consider $-h$ in my proof. I actually checked this example among many simple ones before, but forgot to mention this caveat.

Comment: Modifying the question long after an answer has appeared is not fair. It should have asked  a separate question instead.   @Displayname

Comment: I modified it less than an hour after your answer. If no one answers the question, I will take your advice and repost.